# Why is there no 'is' ufunc in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I can certainly do

```
a[a == 0] = something
```

that sets every entry of `a` that equals zero to `something`. Equivalently, I could write

```
a[np.equal(a, 0)] = something
```

Now, imagine `a` is an array of `dtype=object`. I cannot write `a[a is None]` because, of course, `a` itself isn't `None`. The intention is clear: I want the comparison `is` to be broadcast like any other ufunc. This [list from the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.logic.html) lists nothing like an `is`-unfunc.

Why is there none, and, more interestingly to me: what would be a performant replacement?

Comment: "Why is there none" because the concept doesn't *also* make sense for raw numbers.

Comment: I guess you could try comparing the `id()`s of the objects.

Comment: What would you expect `a = np.array([250, 300, 500]); a[a is 300]` to return?

Comment: @jfaccioni Sure this doesn't make sense (though python evaluates `n is 300` to `True`). But doesn't `isnan` make equally little sense for an integer array? Anyways, I'm not so much interested in *why* things are like that than how to resolve it.

Comment: Did you check if the array is keeping a reference or copying the object? I am assuming that the array is likely copying the object in which case 'is' check is false all the time.

Comment: @AxeonThra Which precisely is *the object*? If multiple elements are `None`, they have the same id, but I'm not sure if I should rely on that.

Comment: `None` is a special case (it's a singleton), so asking *which `None` is this specific `None` object* makes no sense in Python. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Do you want to use `is` in another context - for example, comparing instances of user-defined classes?

Comment: My bad. I understand the question now. I guess the issue is that the 'is' operator cannot be overloaded. It will return a single scalar bool.

Comment: Why do you insist on `is`? `a = np.array([1, None, 0, np.nan, '']); a[a == None] = something` works

Comment: @Reti43: Yes, that's what I'm currently using. But, once I've been taught that None is not to be compared using `==`.

Comment: @Bubaya. Python guarantees `None` to be a singleton. `300` in an array is not a python object in the normal sense to begin with. Individual array elements do not have an object wrapping them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for operations like `reshape` and indexing that don't depend on `dtype` (except for the itemsize), operations on object dtype arrays are performed at list-comprehension speeds, iterating on the elements and applying an appropriate method to each.  Sometimes that method doesn't exist, such as when doing `np.sin`.

To illustrate, consider the array from one of the comments:

```
In [132]: a = np.array([1, None, 0, np.nan, ''])
In [133]: a
Out[133]: array([1, None, 0, nan, ''], dtype=object)
```

The object array test:

```
In [134]: a==None
Out[134]: array([False,  True, False, False, False])
In [135]: timeit a==None
5.16 µs ± 73.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

An equivalent comprehension:

```
In [136]: [x is None for x in a]
Out[136]: [False, True, False, False, False]
In [137]: timeit [x is None for x in a]
1.52 µs ± 18.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

It's faster, even if we cast the result back to array (not a cheap step):

```
In [138]: timeit np.array([x is None for x in a])
4.67 µs ± 95.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Iteration on the list version of the array is even faster:

```
In [139]: timeit np.array([x is None for x in a.tolist()])
2.52 µs ± 48.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Let's look at the full assignment action:

```
In [141]: a[[x is None for x in a.tolist()]]
Out[141]: array([None], dtype=object)
In [142]: %%timeit a1=a.copy()
     ...: a1[[x is None for x in a1.tolist()]] = np.nan
     ...: 
     ...: 
4.03 µs ± 10 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [143]: %%timeit a1=a.copy()
     ...: a1[a1==None] = np.nan
     ...: 
     ...: 
6.18 µs ± 28.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The usual caveat that things might scale differently.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things at play here.

The first (and more important) one is that `is` is implemented directly in the Python interpreter with no option to redirect to a dunder method. Numpy arrays, like many other objects, have an `__eq__` method that implements the `==` operation. `a is None` is treated approximately as `id(a) == id(None)`, with no recourse for an elementwise implementation under any circumstance. That's just how python works.

The second aspect is that numpy is fundamentally designed for storing numbers. Object arrays are special cases that store references to objects as a number. This appears to be the same as how lists store object references, but it's only similar when dealing with references. The elements of a list are always references to objects, even when the list contains homogeneous integers, for example. A numpy array of dtype `int` does **not** contain python objects. Each consecutive element of the array is a raw binary integer, not a reference to a python object wrapper. Even if python allowed you to override the `is` operator, it would be meaningless to apply elementwise.

So if you want to compare objects, use python lists:

```
mylist = [...]
mylist = [something if x is None else x for x in mylist]
```

If you insist on using a numpy array, either (a) use numerical arrays and mark `None` elements with something else, like `np.nan`, or (b) treat the array as a list. You will have to apply `id` or `is` to each element, which are python constructs, so there is no "performant" way to do it at that point, or (c) just use `==`, which will trigger python-level equality comparison, which is equivalent to `is` for the singleton `None`.